# Can we add SSO in managed package?

Tags: apex, oauth2, single-sign-on

I have an app which is using SSO to integrate with salesforce. Salesforce is used as an identity provider. So my question is can I add SSO in managed packaged? Because we want to provide an managed app on appExchange.

Comment: Would love to know for myself as well

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't include SSO settings into a package. The reason being SSO requires both sides (Identity Provider, Service Provider) to be configured in such a way they trust each other.

Since an Identity Provider can serve multiple Service Providers, you can't capture the SSO settings in a package. Setting up SSO requires manual steps on both sides.