# Including SSO in a managed package

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, open-id-connect

We have a Salesforce Managed Package, and we'd like to use it to provide access to a non-Salesforce service (in this case Tableau). The ISVForce Guide indicates that [you can package SAML SSO config in a Connected App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/connected_app_create_saml_sso.htm) but in practice, it seems like you have to specify a particular Salesforce 'My Domain' URL to be the Identity Provider when you setup SSO. This means we can enable SSO to a particular Salesforce org (Ex: https://energy-data-737.cs128.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost), but we don't expect that will work once that configuration is packaged and installed in a different org.

We've experimented with various generic Salesforce URLs as the SAML endpoint. Despite being [referenced in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/sso_saml_idp_values.htm), saml.salesforce.com no longer appears to resolve in DNS. Authentication also fails if we attempt to use test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com; even though we include a username in our SAML information, our login requests don't appear to be routed to our particular org, so we don't even see "login failed" messages in the org.

Is there a generic way to include SSO in a managed package using SAML? If not, is it possible to package OAuth (OpenID Connect) SSO configuration in a managed package? What is a recommended practice here?

Comment: Note, this question was answered "No" over here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91901/can-we-add-sso-in-managed-package

Consider this our request for a workaround

Comment: Your best option is to have your package extract the information via Metadata or whatever APIs after it's installed in a subscriber org. Some of this ground is covered in these questions: [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272741/how-to-create-an-identity-provider-using-the-metadata-api/) [two](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271012/automate-setup-of-an-external-identity-provider-via-apis)

Comment: Thanks for that insight. In those other two questions, the situation was the inverse: dynamically setting up Salesforce as the service provider. But here we want Salesforce to be the Identity provider, ideally using a single generic Salesforce endpoint, instead of org-specific config. Is that possible?

Comment: One of those two questions was for SF as identity provider